# C# serial port ( received, decode and display) droping data issues

Tags: c#, winforms, logging, serial-port, decode

I'm pretty new to all this C# stuff, more used to embedded C. 
I am trying to develope a windows form logger to perform the following:-

1. Receive serial data from port in the form of status frames 14 bytes typically few a second before logging starts. Then 26-byte data frames at a rate of 2000 times a second (52kbytes/s)
2. The frames need to be decoded, checked if valid, sample counter extracted and four 8-bit ADC channels extracted from the frame to export to csv after logging has stopped.
3. Graph one of the ADC channels in the GUI.

I am using the following approach:

1. Using the `serialPort1_DataReceived` event to read `rx data`.
2. This event is also calling the decode function that adds decoded data to a
   struct list
3. GUI has a timer that reads data from struct list to plot in
   chart.
4. ADC channel is 10ksps so every 10th sample is plotted (1ksps
   displayed)

I would expect to see reduction resolution of plotted test signal but parts are missing.
It looks like when the program in decoding and displaying its data received event is dropping bytes. Its there a better approach?

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

   int num_bytes;

   byte[] ecu_status = new byte[140];
   num_bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;                  
   // Console.WriteLine(num_bytes); 

   // status frames muliples of 14 bytes                                                     
   if (num_bytes % 14 == 0 && num_bytes < 140 && _start_log_flag == false)                                                         
   {
      serialPort1.Read(ecu_status, 0, num_bytes);
      decode_status(ecu_status, num_bytes);
    }
   else if (num_bytes > 25)               // data frames 26 bytes                                                                        
   {
      byte[] ecu_data = new byte[num_bytes];
      serialPort1.Read(ecu_data, 0, num_bytes);
      decode_data(ecu_data, num_bytes);
     _start_log_flag = true;
    }
   else serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();    // corupt clear buffer                                                           
}
```

I have updated the above event to this below, it has improved things but I'm still getting a glitch / slight lose of data every 1 second or 10,000 samples?

```
private void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)                              // Receive data event callback
{
    //stopwatch.Stop();                                                                               // Stop timing.
    // Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);                                          // Write result.
    int no_bytes;
    no_bytes = sp.BytesToRead;                                                                         // get num bytes from serial port buffer

    if ((no_bytes == 14 || no_bytes == 28) && !_start_log_flag)                                       // check if status frame\s (14 bytes each) once logging ignore  status frames
    {
        byte[] _rx_data = new byte[no_bytes];                                                          // create array for data 
        sp.Read(_rx_data, 0, no_bytes);                                                                // get status frame\s from serial buffer    
        decode_status(_rx_data, no_bytes);                                                             // decode & process status frame\s
    }
    else if ((no_bytes == 26 || (no_bytes > 51 && no_bytes < 4097)) && _live_stream)                   // check for data frames (26 bytes each)
    {
        _start_log_flag = true;                                                                         // now logging 
        Console.WriteLine(no_bytes);
        byte[] _rx_data1 = new byte[no_bytes];                                                          // create array for data 

        sp.Read(_rx_data1, 0, no_bytes);                                                                // get data frames from comms buffer
        data_frames.Enqueue(_rx_data1);                                                                  // queue array to process later 
    }
    else
    {
        sp.DiscardInBuffer();                                                                           // jibberish clear buffer
    }
    // stopwatch.Reset();
    // stopwatch.Start();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask], [tour] and [mcve] to improve your question

Comment: My guess would be you are reading the data in the event wrong and dont full read every byte that is in the buffer, but without code it is hard to say what you are doing wrong.

Comment: is c# the best way to go? The overhead might be affecting the data.

Comment: Can you please add your `serialPort1_DataReceived` event code?

Comment: This is not a forum, it is a Q&A site. Please edit your question to include this info then delete this answer – Scott Chamberlain 17 hours ago

Comment: Your code should not compile since you are declaring ecu_data twice which is invalid. You are never reseting _start_log_flag to false. I would recommend the using the sender instead of the field SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender; – Rand Random 24 mins ago

Comment: @Rand Random sorry ecu_data was typo, Not sure what you mean about using sender?

Comment: The event handler `serialPort1_DataReceived` has two arguments `object sender` and `SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e` - I would recommend using the first argument `object sender` to get to the `serialPort` that `send` the event. - so instead of using `serialPort1` you should declare a new variable inside your event handler by using the sender eg. `SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;`

Comment: did not really improve things. The serial port is accessing a FTDI USB chip running a 1Mbyte/s

Answer (score 0):

Moving to a memorystream instead of queue reduced the data loss issue greatly. Worst case if 1.99 data frames is recieved at serial and queued, only 1 frame was decoded (50% data loss).

Now constantly taking 400.99 frames from memory stream and decoding 400 (0.25% data loss). Not perfect but alot better

```
        private void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)                             // Receive data event callback
        {
            int no_bytes;
            no_bytes = sp.BytesToRead;                                                                         // get num bytes from serial port buffer

            if ((no_bytes == 14 || no_bytes == 28) && !_start_log_flag)                                        // check if status frame\s (14 bytes each) once logging ignore  status frames
            {
                byte[] _rx_data = new byte[no_bytes];                                                          // create array for data 
                sp.Read(_rx_data, 0, no_bytes);                                                                // get status frame\s from serial buffer    
                decode_status(_rx_data, no_bytes);                                                             // decode & process status frame\s
            }
            else if ((no_bytes > 25 && no_bytes < 4097) && _live_stream)                                        // check for data frames (26 bytes each)
            {
                _start_log_flag = true;                                                                         // now logging 
                byte[] _rx_data1 = new byte[no_bytes];                                                          // create array for data 
                int temp = sp.Read(_rx_data1, 0, no_bytes);                                                     // read data frames from comms buffer
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);                                                                     // ensure orign at the end of memory stream
                ms.Write(_rx_data1, 0, _rx_data1.Length);                                                       // add data to memory stream
            }
            else
            {
                sp.DiscardInBuffer();                                                                           // jibberish clear buffer
            }
        }
```